# Export IBConsole settings (interbase)

Tags: export, application-settings, interbase

How can I export or extract IBConsole settings? I only need the servers I have added and their corresponding Interbase databases that I have added under each one. It is the same server/computer.

The only difference for me  is that I have made a new user and would like it to have all the servers/databases that I have already setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to copy out the xml file of settings from your AppData directory (for Windows 8/Windows Server 2012).
First make sure IBConsole is closed.
Copy the xml file from the user desired, from this path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\InterBase\IBConsole.xml. Then paste it into the same directory for the target user. Open IBConsole, it should now have the settings copied across with all the servers and databases.