# IBConsole Interactive SQL window does not appear

Tags: interbase

When I click the 'Interactive SQL' button on my IBConsole, no window appears.
It is listed when I then click the 'active windows' button, but selecting it and clicking 'Switch to' does nothing.
Is there a known cause for this, or logging somewhere on my system?

Comment: are you perhaps having multiple screens or at least used one once? if so, it is possible the window exists, but somewhere far to the right outside view. try digging around in ibconsole config you can find [the most likely location for the config here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269196). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ hope it works.

Comment: I found the config file to be damaged, will compare with other installations' config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by a corrupted IBConsole.xml settings file, located in C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\InterBase
The cause is unknown to me, but I replaced the file with a colleague's copy, and after that my Interactive SQL window functioned as normal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).